# Passing a map to an apex:attribute

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, map

I have a component

```
<apex:component> <apex:attribute name="ssMap" type="Map"/>       
</apex:component>
```

and I have a page which consumes the component

```
<apex:page controller="SomeController"> 
    <c:someComponent ssMap="{!ssMap}"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Yet when I try to compile the page, I get an error:

```
Wrong type for attribute <c:someComponent> ssMap="{!ssMap}";. Expected Map, found Map<Map<String,Field>>; (Line: 1, Column: -1)
```

From what I understand, I can't define the map types in the attribute. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error is weird as

`Map<Map<String,field>>`

is not even a valid object as it is missing the first map key.

What you could do is create a class (if the `Map<Key,Map<Key, Value>>` does not work)

```
public class myMapParameter{
      Map<Key,Map<Key,Value>> item = New Map<Key,Map<Key,Value>>();
}
```

then define your component as

```
<apex:component> 
      <apex:attribute name="ssMap" type="myMapParameter"/>
</apex:component>
```

from the type definition:

> The Apex data type of the attribute. If using the assignTo attribute
>   to assign the value of this attribute to a controller class variable,
>   the value for type must match the data type of the class variable.
>   Only the following data types are allowed as values for the type
>   attribute:
>
> - Primitives, such as String, Integer, or Boolean.
> - sObjects, such as Account, My_Custom_Object__c, or the generic sObject type.
> - One-dimensional lists, specified using array-notation, such as    String[], or Contact[].
> - Maps, specified using type="map". You don't    need to specify the map's specific data type.
> - Custom Apex types    (classes).

Since lists are required to be one dimensional, maybe maps follow the same pattern even if not explicitly stated

Comment: yep, this worked. Made the type the controller and just passed that in. Thanks!